# Scaling a background image inside a li

Tags: javascript, css, background

I have a basic slider operating on a site.

I have pretty hi-res images so I could scale the images a couple hundred px.  Any ideas how I could scale the background images to a certain point? The images are currently at 1000px per slide, would like to scale the bg width to like 1300px... if the browser is that wide...

Open to CSS or js, would be nice to be ie7+ compatible and functional on other browsers.

any ideas?

Comment: If you are using the images as div elements' background, it'll grow with the div (till it's maximum size, smaller div will have cropped bg).  If you are using img tag to show images, just give its CSS " width: 100%"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove it from background and position images as absolute

```
selectior-name-if-any img{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
```

}

should work in IE7 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-o-background-size: width height;         
-webkit-background-size: width height;   
-khtml-background-size: width height;    
-moz-background-size: width height;     
background-size: width height;
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/tfazD/

Comment: What kind of browser support does that have?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from best practices (images should only be as big as they are displayed) you could just use the CSS property [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), sadly this is not yet fully supported, so you would have to drop support for poor IE.

Using JS you could check `window.innerWidth` (`document.documentElement.clientWidth` for IE) and apply the `background-size`-property if it fits the viewport (the CSS way would be [media-queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)). For IE you would have to hide the background-image and use its proprietary `filter` with a `sizingMethod='scale'` declaration.

Alternatively you could inject an  tag via JS (if browser doesn't support the background-size property (to detect this, you could use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/))) and apply a `z-index:-9999;` to it, so it stays in the background.

Using JS you could also establish some sort of conditional lazy loading technique to load different sizes of the image depending on the user's viewport size (mobile users don't need 1300²px) - dropping support for IE8 and earlier you could also use CSS's media queries mentioned above to load different background-images (or use something like [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) to emulate media queries for IE)